# SwipeRefreshLayout with EmptyView nullPointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, swiperefreshlayout

Whenever I swipe down to refresh, I get a NullPointerException but it's not in *my code*, rather in the startRefresh() method from SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.startRefresh(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:441)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onTouchEvent(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:399)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7253)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2215)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1458)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2163)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7433)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
07-14 11:55:06.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20484):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

This is my onCreate and onRefresh of my main Activity, MonitoredCoursesActivity:

```
public class MonitoredCoursesActivity extends ListActivity implements OnRefreshListener {

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
private ArrayList<Course> monitored;
private String lastUpdate;
private ListView myList;
private MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
final Context context = this;
//  private int freqUpdate;
//  private String updateTime;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (loadState()==null) {
        monitored = new ArrayList<Course>();
    }
    myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(context, R.layout.row, monitored);
    View empty = findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    myList.setEmptyView(empty);
    myList.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
    myList.setLongClickable(true);
    registerForContextMenu(myList);

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
            android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    swipeLayout.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            //Refresh all courses in the list
            updateCoursesInfo();
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="@string/courses" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:divider="#D5DDDE"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:alpha="0.18"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:text="@string/empty_list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

My row.xml for ListView items:

`

```
     <GridLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:columnCount="2" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtCourseName"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
             android:paddingRight="5dp"
             android:text="@string/section"
             android:textSize="25sp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtSection"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_column="1"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_row="0"
             android:text="@string/section"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     </GridLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtRemaining"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
         android:text="@string/remaining"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtCRN"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/crn"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtFecha"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
 </LinearLayout>`
```

I've searched and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298214/exception-dispatching-input-event-and-null-pointer-exception-on-swiperefreshlayo) is the only similar question, but the solution doesn't apply to my case (or at least I think so). Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
context = this;
```

in `onCreate`

In

```
myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(context, R.layout.row, monitored);// here you are using context
```

`Context` is available once activity is created

Line 441 is

```
mListener.onRefresh();
```

Looking at the source

```
public void setOnRefreshListener(OnRefreshListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

So have you implemented `OnRefreshListener` properly in your Activity?

As discussed in the chat

Remove the second `SwipeRefreshLayout`

To set a empty view to listview read the below instead of having the other swiperefreshlayout

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/

Comment: It's declared as a field above the onCreate() `final Context context = this`;

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta `Context context` is declaration . Initialize `context =this` in `onCreate`. Also it need not be final.

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta no. do it in `onCreate` is what i mentioned.

Comment: Still get the error it after following your recommendation.

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta that's one mistake.

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta you can look at the source and check the line number form stacktrace and fix the problem https://github.com/futuresimple/android-support-v4/blob/master/src/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta source hints that you have not implemented `OnRefreshListener` in your Activity properly and this  in `swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);` refers to Activity

Comment: the Activity implements OnRefreshListener and I overrode the method. It's all up there, right below the onCreate()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57280/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-hugo-m-zuleta).

Answer (score 1):

So, after a long talk with user Raghunandan here, he pointed out that my xml had two different SwipeRefreshLayouts. This workaround was used in order to properly set an EmptyView on the ListView (as shown on the onCreate() method), but was all rubbish. The EmptyView worked, but one of those SwipeRefreshLayouts had a null onRefreshListener (the one for the EmptyView, of course). THIS caused the NullPointerException, naturally. Every piece of code remains the same. The only thing I had to change was the activity_main.xml:

> 

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="@string/courses" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:divider="#D5DDDE"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:alpha="0.18"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:text="@string/empty_list"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal" />
```

**Note: If you're having issues with ContextMenus not appearing, even after being correctly declared, this should fix it.**

Be careful with your layouts!